# Python typing to allow one or a list of values

Tags: python, python-typing

I am wanting to be able to add a type annotation that accepts either one or a list of the defined type.

For example, the first func would accept a str or a list of strs, and the second a Path or list of paths.

```
def foo(names: Listable[str]):
    pass

def bar(paths: Listable[Path]):
    pass

foo('a')         # correct type
foo(['a', 'b'])  # correct type
foo([1, 2])      # wrong type
```

`Listable[str]` is equivalent to `Union[str, list[str]]`

Is there a way to achieve this in Python using generics or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by taking any number of arguments as a list, and then checking at the very beginning of the function and throwing an error if it is unallowed.

```py
def foo(var):
    if type(var).__name__ == 'list':
        for item in var:
            if type(item).__name__ != 'str':
                raise TypeError('foo only accepts lists of strings or a string, was given a list containing a type '+ type(item).__name__)                  
    
    elif type(var).__name__ != 'str': 
        raise TypeError('foo only accepts lists of strings or a string, was given type '+type(var).__name__)

    pass
```

The function will initially accept any type `var`, and then we manually type-check it and throw a proper TypeError exception if we're given the wrong types.

See the Python documentation for [TypeError Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)
and this [rollbar article about throwing exceptions](https://rollbar.com/blog/throwing-exceptions-in-python/) for further reading about the technical stuff.

Using your example values, my terminal printed this out:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m.py", line 17, in <module>
    z = foo([1, 2]) 
  File "m.py", line 8, in foo
    raise TypeError('foo only accepts lists of strings or a string, was given a list containing a type '+ type(item).__name__)      
TypeError: foo only accepts lists of strings or a string, was given a list containing a type int
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `*args` instead

```py
from typing import Any


def foo(*names: Any) -> None:
    for name in names:
        print(name)

foo("a")  # OK!
foo("a", "b", "c")  # OK as well!
```